# ssh config to "prepend" torsocks

Tags: ssh, tor

I can reach my phone using:

```
torsocks ssh myphone
```

if I have this in my `.ssh/config`:

```
Host myphone
  User u0_a162
  Port 2222
  HostName umqkh75wp2chf5av5esqhtyzedmw4it76dvs7ild2rikbcek6eyqfsqd.onion
```

Can I somehow adapt the `.ssh/config` so that I can simply write this and run the same:

```
ssh myphone
```

Can I somehow move the `torsocks` into `.ssh/config` - possibly with ProxyCommand or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this as the ProxyCommand:

```
ProxyCommand nc -x localhost:9050 -X 5 umqkh75wp2chf5av5esqhtyzedmw4it76dvs7ild2rikbcek6eyqfsqd.onion 2222
```